# Google Drive API not returning folders until opened in web client

Tags: python, list, api, file, drive

I have a Google Drive account which has folders shared to it from a few other accounts - not team drives, but normal folders with sharing turned on. I'm trying to use the Drive API to list all folders shared to it, and all folders contained within those. For example, if folder A is shared with me:

```
A
| 
|-- 1
|   |
|   |--file1.png
|    --file2.png
|
|-- 2
|   |
|   |--file3.png
|    --file4.png
|
 -- 3
    |
    |--file5.png
     --file6.png
```

If I use `files.list` in the Drive API (at this point, just interacting with it through the web interface https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list), and specify `mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'`, only folder A will be returned, but not folders 1, 2 or 3.

However, if I log into Google Drive through the web interface and open folder 1, then try using `files.list` again, it'll return folders A and 1, but not 2 and 3. This behaviour seems to be completely consistent.

I've tried changing the search's scope, switching `supportsAllDrives` and `includeItemsFromAllDrives` to true, and using the `user` and `allDrives` corpora.

Is there a reason Google Drive only returns folders once I've opened them in the web client? This search should be returning hundreds of folders, and it's cumbersome to open them all with the web interface, as well as not being future-proof for if those drives add new folders without notifying me. If it's intentional, is there a way I can circumvent it to return all folders instead?

Thank you for your help! Hopefully I haven't left out any important information.

Comment: I would like to correctly understand about your question. About `at this point, just interacting with it through the web interface https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list`, in this case, does this mean to use "Try this API"?

Comment: That's correct, yes

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, for example, the value of `'###folderID of 1### in parents or '###folderID of 2### in parents or '###folderID of 3### in parents` is used for `q` of "Try this API" of Files: list, what result will you get? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) By the way, in you tags, "python" can be seen. Can I ask you about the meaning of this?

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** I used JavaScript with Google Apps Script, but the solution would generally apply to all languages.

**Note #2:** I am using the Drive API v2

I was having this same problem and resolved it by adding `corpora: 'allDrives'` as a request param, so now I have:

```
const result = Drive.Files.list({
  q: `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false`,
  pageToken: pageToken,
  spaces: "drive",
  fields: "nextPageToken, items(id, title, parents)",
  corpora: 'allDrives',
  supportsAllDrives: true,
  includeItemsFromAllDrives: true,
});
```

Besides that you might want to make sure you are correctly using `pageToken` and also make sure that the folders you want to find are explicitly shared with you.

Comment: corpora: 'allDrives' is what I'm missing. This should be the accepted answer